# Add an extended set of plugins to a fresh QGIS installation

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

There are a number of non-default QGIS plugins I use every day that are not included in a fresh installation of QGIS. [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/), [QConsolidate](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/) are just to name a few - I think everyone has their own list. Unfortunatelly, every time I install QGIS to a new machine I have to manually download every item on this list. So I wonder if there is a way to add reference to such plugins to a fresh QGIS installation.

The best think I came up with so far is to restore my list with a backup of "plugins" directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have a windows installation?

QGIS stores his settings (and plugins, scripts, etc) under C:\Users\yourusername\.qgis2

If you copy this folder to the newly installed computers (and replace the old folder), you get your preferences/plugins/scripts you want.